# How to enable Web Services Extension folder on IIS 6

Tags: windows-xp, iis-6

I'm trying to get .asp pages working on Windows Internet Information Server 6.0 on **Win XP Pro** *(I originally mistakenly posted this as Home)*.

I found instructions in several places that say I should enable it in the Web Services Extension folder.

Problem is that my IIS6 doesn't have that folder under the local computer.

Update:  I tried getting it to work with IIS5 but (as noted below) the instructions call for a WSE folder that isn't present.

So I installed IIS6.  Hence my question is about IIS6.

Do I perhaps need to uninstall IIS6

Answer (score 2):

IIRC XP has IIS 5.1, not 6.0, so the instructions for "Web Services Extension" do not apply

I recall IIS 5.1 only allowing ASP support on a virtual folder, not on the root level for some reason?

Have you run the IIS lockdown tool and locked out ASP? Need to undo that :-)

Check http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000329.html for other hints